# Определение уязвимости к SQL-инъекции по URL

Tags: уязвимости, mysql

Как выяснить, есть ли на каком-либо сайте скрипты, уязвимые к SQL injection? Слышал, есть даже спец. программы, но меня интересует, как определить самостоятельно по URL-у.

Comment: **Эх, Артем, займись ты лучше делом.**

Comment: Почитайте статьи по безопасности и используйте плейсхолдеры в SQL запросах.

Comment: А так трудно написать id=1 or id>0?

Answer (score 2):

По URL?) Если бы все было так просто)) Уязвимость может быть и в POST-запросе. В GET достаточно изменить любые данные на что-то из SQL

> http://www.site.ru/news.php?news_id='--

Если это выдаст ошибку, уязвимость есть. Это общий случай, адрес, переменные и пр. меняются.

Comment: Кавычки могут быть двойными, так что случай с `'` может прокатить :)

Comment: Ошибка по кавычке в id (например если id д.б. числом) вовсе не означает, что есть подобная уязвимость.

Comment: @avp, имелось в виду не "Запись не найдена", а фатальный отказ и "Check syntax in...")

Answer (score 0):

Забыли добавить, что sql инъекции бывают и в куках. Всё, что можно отправить на сайт, может быть потенциальной инъекцией или xss.

Чтоб найти на сайте инъекцию, нужно знать основы и особенности SQL сервера и самого языка SQL, судя по вопросу, следует начать изучение именно с этих пунктов.